# Local printing from Citrix, job is paused and sends 128KB on each resume

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing, citrix

I have a very strange issue that is affecting non-domain admin users.  When a standard user within Citrix (Presentation Server 4.0) attempts to print to a local printer (attached via USB to the local computer) the job comes up in the server printer queue straight away as paused.

If the user right-clicks the job in the printer queue and selects Resume the job status changes to Paused - Printing, but doesn't print.

I have been able to narrow down, that if I send a test job from notepad to the printer, the job comes up as Paused but after clicking Resume the print job is then sent to the local computers printer queue.

I then did a test in Word and again the printer job displays as Paused in the Printer queue, however when clicking resume the amount of data sent to the printer is 128KB, and clicking resume again increased to 256KB and continuing this each time the job was resumed until it reached the size of the job and then the job appears in the local printer queue.

The notepad test document was only 9KB and the Word document was 619KB.  I have been able to replicate this 128KB data sending with several different test jobs from Word and also the Printer test page.  On all occassions it will send 128KB (or the size of the job), and then requires an additional resume to complete the job transmission.

The environment is:

- Local PC: Windows XP Professional SP3 32-bit
- Local Printer: HP LaserJet Professional CP1020
- Server: Windows Server 2003 Standard 32-bit
- Citrix: Citrix Presentation Server 4.0

The printer driver in use in the Citrix environment has been mapped to the Citrix Universal Print Driver, removing this forced maping makes the print driver in use on the Citrix server the HP LaserJet print driver (which has been added to the Server 2003 environment), however this then results in only ~1.3KB (appears to change on each resume) being sent to the printer on each resume.

**Edit:** The printer name is HPCP1020, as I have read that Citrix has an issue with long names, but this still resulted in the same behaviour.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience of what is occuring and how we could go about resolving this issue or debugging this further?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: In some occasions manufacturer will release a special driver for the printer, you might want to check into that. As well, changing format of the job might yield some results.